# MSSQL+ODBC+PHP = 0 rows in result

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, pivot, freetds

I'm using remote MSSQL base via php + linux ODBC. All was fine, but today i wrote query with `SET` + `PIVOT` and got error:

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]SELECT failed because the following SET options have 
incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL,
ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views 
and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or 
XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

I tried to write SET `ANSI_NULLS ON` etc but it wont works, there is 0 fields in result.
The same query executed directly on server via MSSQL studio works perfectly.
Any idea where can be a problem?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
freetds.conf

```
[syserver]
host =192.168.1.200
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
AnsiNPW=YES
QuotedID=YES
```

odbc.ini

```
[sy_odbc]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description  = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace = No
Servername = syserver
Database = Insy
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
FileUsage = 1
```

Before I `got tds version=6.0`, and after changing it up to 7.0 all errors such `ANSI_NULLS` gone, but I still have 0 rows in result. `AnsiNPW=YES` and `QuotedID=YES` do nothing for me. If try to change version to 8.0 in result of simple query i have `??????????`. `TDS_version=7.0` in `odbc.ini` also do nothing.

My query [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88499/2).
And my connection string is: `$conn=odbc_connect('sy_odbc','t','t');`

**Update 2:**
Some of my php pages stop working when i had changed `TDS_version to 7.0` or `7.2`, so i return it back to 6.0.
Connection string as you proposed don't work for me. At all. (I'm using mine more than year, and it was fine, before that issue)
[Here](http://pastebin.com/gNsbBWjq) is errorlog for problem query with 6.0 version (here we have `ANSI_NULLS` etc warnings)
[Here](http://pastebin.com/M4eSQKgd) is errorlog for problem query with 7.0 version (There is no warnings, but 0 rows in result)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416814/set-connection-settings-with-pyodbc-unixodbc-freetds) might be helpful to you. If that doesn't fix you up I'd recommend changing the `tds version` value in your freetds.conf and/or `TDS_Version` value in your odbc.ini. If none of that works, update your question with your full freetds.conf, odbcinst.ini, odbc.ini, the SQL statement you're trying to execute and the code showing how you connect to the database.

Comment: I'm sorry Sergii, I am out of ideas :-( I saw no error message in the log when you had TDS version = 7.0. I am assuming you are checking the return value of your `odbc_exec()` statement and it's not === FALSE? If it is returning FALSE you should execute `odbc_errormsg()`.

Comment: @BennyHill, anyway, thank You for help.  Actually, the second paragraph of post is result of `echo odbc_errormsg();` :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two more things I can think of Sergii:

1) Your connection string. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) says your connection string should look like this:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('Driver={sy_odbc};Server=192.168.1.200;Database=Insy', $username, $password);
```

So I'd give that a try first and see if it helps.

2) Any time you are having problems with ODBC connections you should turn on logging so you can capture error messages. To do this add the following lines to your /etc/odbcinst.ini file:

```
[ODBC]
Trace     = yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
```

If your query still doesn't work, edit your question and add the output from the odbc.log file (assuming there are error messages in it).

Comment: i have tried your proposition, look result in update, please.